# Problems with jQuery event chain in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, safari

I'm building a simple photolog using jQuery, jflickrfeed and jQuery.Masonry - but I'm having some trouble getting the event chain right in Safari.

Here's some example code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').jflickrfeed({
        limit: 20,
        qstrings: {
            id: '58201136@N00'
        },
        itemTemplate: '<div class="box"><img src="{{image_m}}" /><h3>{{title}}</h3>{{description}}</div>'
    }, function(data) {
        console.log("1st");
    });
});

$(window).load(function() {
    console.log("2nd");
    $('#container').masonry({
        singleMode: true
    });
});
```

So, jflickrfeed pulls a photo from my flickr feed, wraps it in the template code and appends it inside #container, and repeats this until the limit is reached. After all photos are inserted, Masonry kicks in and arranges the divs.

This works beautifully in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari - where the .load event fires before all photos are finished loaded, thus breaking the layout.

I've updated the example to better show illustrate what I mean.
In Chrome/Firefox the console output is "1st, 2nd" while in Safari it is "2nd, 1st"

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself by adding a counter:

```
var counter = 0; 

$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#container').jflickrfeed({ 
        limit: 20, 
        qstrings: { 
            id: '58201136@N00' 
        }, 
        itemTemplate: '<div class="box"><img src="{{image_m}}" /><h3>{{title}}</h3>{{description}}</div>', 
        itemCallback: function () { 
            counter++; 
        } 
    }); 
}); 

$(window).load(function () { 
    var i = setInterval(function () { 
        if (counter = 20) { 
            $('#container').masonry({ 
                singleMode: true 
            }); 
            clearInterval(i); 
        } 
    }, 20); 
});
```

Ugly, but it works..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how useful this will be, or if if will make any difference at all. But for a guess, if the issue is that `#container` is not available when `$(window).load` fires, you could try setting up a timer to repeatedly check for its existence, and when it is detected, set up masonry, then kill the timer:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    var i = setInterval(function() {
        if($("#container").length) {
            $('#container').masonry({
                singleMode: true
            });
            clearInterval(i);
        }}, 
    20);
});
```

Comment: What was that first code you posted? It worked like magic, but for some reason this doesn't..

Comment: @jonnablaze - yes it is. Now I'm really confused :|

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. I've updated the example code to better illustrate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the load callback as the second parameter to "jflickrfeed" call and this will ensure that the "masonry" will be invoked only when the images from Flickr have been loaded.

here is a possible sample:

```
$('#container').jflickrfeed({
    limit: 20,
    qstrings: {
        id: '58201136@N00'
    },
    itemTemplate: '<div class="box"><img src="{{image_m}}" /><h3>{{title}}</h3>{{description}}</div>'
}, 
function () {
    $('#container').masonry({
        singleMode: true
    });
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've updated the example code to better illustrate the problem.